# How to escape characters within Marp?

Tags: markdown, marp

I am trying to create a presentation in Marp but when I do "{1+2} is 3" within a code block, it gets rendered as "  is 3". Is there any way I can escape the characters to have it rendered properly?.

Here is the code block:

[image]

Here is the rendered output:

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific with how you're rendering this?  For example, I typed the above code into VSCode's Marp editor and it works just fine.  I also used "Export slide deck" which uses markdown.marp.export to create a PDF and that contains the `{1+2}` as well.